# Failure: Android library projects cannot be launched

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to build and run (using eclipse) an application on my Android phone that I've downloaded from a tutorial but I'm getting the following message:

"Android Library Projects cannot be launched". Never seen this before.

Any thoughts on what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In project properties, under "Android", there's a checkbox "Is Library". It's probably checked now. That means the project is a library.

Sometimes, library projects can be used as standalone apps - they have a manifest, launchable activities and everything. Sometimes they're not. Anyway, uncheck and give it a try.